# skip header of csv file to be imported in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, csv, import, workbench

What I did is to type this query:

```
SELECT * FROM report;
```

then click the Import Records from an External File in MySQL Workbench. It worked and it was imported in my database. The problem is that the header is also imported.

What should I do to import everything except the header?

Answer (score 3):

Ive never really used MySQL workbench, but the best way to import a .csv is with LOAD DATA INFILE.

Example:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '{$file_path}' INTO TABLE {$table} FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES
```

Note that your LINES TERMINATED BY may be different based on the way your .csv is formatted. It could also be \n' or less commonly '\r'.

Comment: I have the error "Out of range on the first column..", what does that mean?

Comment: You probably have a value in the first column of the data you are loading that exceeds either the character limit or number of decimal places that the first column allows. What is the type of your first column?

Comment: my first column is my primary key. auto_increment. I think I know now the problem because when I checked the number of columns, I missed two from the csv. May be that's why. :)